# Data saved in Stack content keep changing, can't increment

Tags: c, stack, push, peek

So here is my issue, I have been trying to figure this out for the last 5 hours, I have a header file, a tester file, and a c source file. I would really like to understand what is happening and why so I can avoid the issue in the future. The header file declares the struct but does not define it:

`typedef struct Stack *StackP;`

and in my source file, Stack.c I have defined the stack:

```
struct Stack
{
  int top;
  int capacity;
  int count;
  ItemT items;
};
```

where `ItemT` is defined as `char *`

in the tester file, the call goes:

`StackP stackPtr = newStack();`

and what I have for my newStack function located in the c source file is:

```
StackP newStack(void) {
  struct Stack stack1;
  StackP stackPtr = &stack1;
  (stackPtr->items) = (ItemT)malloc(DEFAULT_CAPACITY*sizeof(ItemT));        

  (stackPtr->top) = -1;
  (stackPtr->capacity) = DEFAULT_CAPACITY;
  (stackPtr->count) = 0;    
  fprintf(stderr, "\nSuccesfully allocated memory to items...\n");

  return stackPtr;
}
```

now, my push function is:

```
void pushStack(StackP stackPtr, ItemT item) {           
  if ((stackPtr->count) == (stackPtr->capacity)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "\nERROR: Full stack.\n");
  }
  else {
    stackPtr->items = item;
    fprintf(stderr, "\nSuccessfully pushed %s on to the stack...\n", stackPtr->items);
    (stackPtr->items)++;
    (stackPtr->top)++;
    (stackPtr->count)++;
  }
}
```

My question is this: Have I don't something wrong in any of these blocks of code.

If I call a function that says:

`return (stackPtr->count);`

it will return a random set of numbers instead of 0, or 1. For instance, if I push 2 strings to the stack, instead of count being 2, count is `479622` or some other random long number. Why is this happening?

Again, I would like to know what I'm doing wrong and not just correct syntax because I really HAVE to understand this.

Comment: `return stackPtr;` do you realize you're returning the address of an automatic variable (`struct Stack stack1;`), resulting in a dangling pointer that invokes *undefined behavior* to utilize?

Comment: In `newStack` you return a local variable as pointer, which is no good (you should malloc that) - Site note: please remove the C++ tag

Comment: You should move the definition of the `Stack` structure to a header file so it can be shared by other source files.  Sometimes, the compiler needs to know more details than a forward declaration provides.

Answer (score 7):

The program has undefined behaviour as it is returning the address of a local variable from a function:

```
StackP newStack(void) {
  struct Stack stack1;
  StackP stackPtr = &stack1;

  return stackPtr;
}
```

`stack1` no longer exists when `newStack` exits. `stackPtr` must point to dynamically allocated memory if it is to exist beyond the scope of the function:

```
StackP newStack(void) {
  struct Stack stack1;
  StackP stackPtr = malloc(sizeof(*stackPtr));
  if (stackPtr)
  {
  }

  return stackPtr;
}
```

---

See [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: @FrankPalmasani keep in mind, you do *not* need to dynamically allocate your `Stack` if you change the return type of your function to `struct Stack` rather than `StackP`. In other words, returning `stack1` and having the function return a `struct Stack` (*not* a pointer-to) would be sufficient, so long as you also account for this in the free-logic.

Comment: @hmjd yeah, it may be an unstated outer requirement the structure itself be dynamic, but from what I see, there is currently no reason it *must* be so. It definitely makes the `newStack()` implementation shorter (two lines).